# Websockets + Spring boot + Kubernetes

Tags: spring, websocket, kubernetes, spring-websocket

I am creating a Facebook multiplayer game and am currently evaluating my tech stack.

My game would need to use websockets and I would like to use Spring Boot. Now, I can not find the info if websocket server will work nicely in Kubernetes? For example if I deploy 5 instances of the server in Kubernetes pods will load balancing/forwarding work correctly for websockets between game clients loaded in browsers and servers in Kubernetes and is there any additional work to enable it? Each pod/server would be stateless and current game info for each player will be stored/read from redis or some other memory db.

If this would not work, how can I work around it and still use Kubernetes? Maybe add one instance of rabbitmq to the stack just for the websockets?

Comment: The "problem" with websockets is that they do not load balance well because the connection is persistent. If you have 3 severs and during connection time you round robin which server the users connects to you will initially have an equal load across the servers. As users disconnect you will start having unequal load. Depending on your system design this may not be a problem. The idea of backing your sockets with a queue server is good, but also look at using redis for that.

Comment: K8S is just an instrument of orchestration. Its network runs over the transport layer (TCP/UDP) or over HTTP if Ingress is used. So there will be no problem with Kubernetes. However, as @Leon said in the comments, you need to think carefully about the balancing and distribution of the websocket connections.

Answer (score 1):

I just completed a production rollout of a WebSocket server (built using Spring boot) on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) leveraging Kafka as State of the World (SoTW) without any sub-protocol such as STOMP etc.

I would like to share my experience. Some of the challenges and solutions are already listed in the answers. However, I would consolidate it here.

**Challenges:**

1. **Persistent Connections:** Kubernetes' load balancing mechanisms might not natively support long-lived WebSocket connections, requiring additional configuration or dedicated ingress controllers like NGINX or Envoy.
2. **Session Stickiness:** Ensuring consistent connections to the same pod for a user session can be challenging, often necessitating session affinity rules or sticky sessions.
3. **Increased Complexity:** Managing WebSockets on Kubernetes adds a layer of complexity, requiring a deeper understanding of Kubernetes concepts and configuration.
4. **Monitoring and Troubleshooting:** Troubleshooting WebSocket issues within a cluster can be more involved due to the distributed nature and multiple layers of infrastructure.

**Deciding Factors:**

1. **Traffic Volume and Variability:** If your WebSocket server experiences high or unpredictable traffic, Kubernetes' scalability and high availability features become highly beneficial.
2. **Deployment Frequency:** If you need to update or deploy new versions of your WebSocket server frequently, Kubernetes' streamlined deployment processes are advantageous.
3. **Integration Requirements:** If your application involves complex interactions between WebSocket servers and other services, Kubernetes' service discovery and integration capabilities are valuable.
4. **Team Expertise:** Consider your team's familiarity with Kubernetes and willingness to manage the added complexity.

**Best Practices:**

1. **Choose an Ingress Controller:** Select an ingress controller that supports WebSockets well, such as NGINX or Envoy.
2. **Configure Session Affinity:** Implement session affinity rules to ensure consistent connections to the same pod.
3. **Monitor and Debug Effectively:** Use tools and techniques for monitoring and debugging WebSockets within Kubernetes.
4. **Consider Service Mesh:** For advanced load balancing and service-to-service communication, explore service mesh solutions like Istio.

Deploying WebSocket servers on Kubernetes offers significant benefits in terms of scalability, high availability, resource optimization, and deployment management. However, it's crucial to address the challenges of persistent connections, session stickiness, and increased complexity. Carefully evaluate your application's requirements and team expertise to make an informed decision.

Also, You seem to be on the right track and since this question is a bit old, please share your experience as well how you ended up implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

An adequate way to handle this would be to use "sticky sessions". This is where the user is pinned down to a specific pod based on the setting of a cookie.

Here is an example of configuring the `Ingress` resource object to use sticky sessions:

```
#
# https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/affinity/cookie
#
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1  
kind: Ingress  
metadata:  
  name: nginx-test-sticky
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: $HOST
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: $SERVICE_NAME
          servicePort: $SERVICE_PORT
```

Now with that being said, the *proper* way to handle this would be to use a message broker or a websocket implementation that supports clustering such as socketcluster (https://socketcluster.io).